# Azure Automation Account PS Remote into Azure VM

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to check some Windows Services in an Azure VM using an Automation Account with managed identity using a Powershell script.

Basically I'm trying to use the New-PSsession -computerName VM1 command

```
$VMS = @('VMINT01p', 'VMINT02p', 'VMINT03p', 'VMINT04p')

Foreach ($VM in $VMS)
{
    $testSession = New-PSsession -ComputerName $VM -ErrorAction Stop
    if(-not($testSession))
    {
        write-host "Failed to connect to $VM"
        Throw "Unable to remote..."
    }
    else 
    {
        write-host "Connected to $VM"
        
    }
    
}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException:
> Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message :
> The WinRM client cannot process the request.  If the authentication
> scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not
> joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the
> destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration
> setting.  Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers
> in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. You can get more
> information about that by running the following command: winrm help
> config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
> Help topic.

I already gave the automation account managed identity **Virtual Machine Administrator Login**, but I'm wondering if that is the correct permissions to get this to work with the automation account.

I'm able to run this script under my own credentials, but I have the admin group permission in the indows OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are doing the correct way to connect Azure VM using PowerShell.

Please check the below steps once if you are following the same:

#### Prerequisites

```
# Install AzureRM PowerShell module  to connect to Azure VMs
Install-Module AzureRM

# Verify the WinRM service is running on your local machine
Start-Service WinRM

# Add the VM's public IP address to the trusted hosts of the local machine
Set-Item WSMan:\<localhost>\Client\TrustedHosts -Value <Public IP address of the VM>
```

#### Open the ports in the network security group

Open your **WinRM** (Windows Remote Management) **HTTP** and **HTTPS** ports on **NSG** associated with VM.

##### Commands to retrieve the NSG to add rules are below:

```
Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name <NSGNAME> -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName>
```

##### Add the NSG Config Rule to connect VM

```
Add-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name AllowingWinRMHTTPS -Description "To Enable PowerShell Remote Access" -Access <Allow/Deny> -Protocol <Protocal_type = Tcp> -Direction <Inbound/Outbound> -Priority <102> -SourceAddressPrefix <SrcAddPrefix = Internet> -SourcePortRange <port range = *> -DestinationAddressPrefix <DestAddPrefix = *>  DestinationPortRange <Port you want to use 5986>
```

##### save rule in NSG

```
Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup
```

#### To access the VM using PowerShell

- Enable **WinRM** on the VM
- Open the required **WinRM** firewall ports on the VM (if the local Windows Firewall is activated).

Create an empty PowerShell script on local

```
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\<fileName>.ps1
```

Add/Store the tasks in the file which you want to do in VM.

```
    $Content = "winrm qc /force
    
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name= WinRMHTTP dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=5985
    
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name= WinRMHTTPS dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=5986"
```

Add tasks to the PowerShell script

```
    Add-Content C:\<fileName>.ps1 $Content
```

Run script inside the VM using the  ***VMRunCommand***.

```
    Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <name> -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath C:\<fileName>.ps1
```

Remove the script (because we don't need it anymore)

```
    Remove-Item C:\<fileName>.ps1
```

#### Connect to VM using PowerShell

From here you can able to connect the VM's.

```
    Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <The public IP address of the VM>
```

Refer [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/connect-to-azure-vm-using-powershell/#Content-bal-title) for more information.

PowerShell to connect VMs with [Azure PSRemoting](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/powershell-basics-connecting-to-vms-with-azure-psremoting/ba-p/428403)